# How to build bucket after multiple nested aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have problem with creating bucket after nested aggregation

```
"events.name12": {
         "filter": {},
         "aggs": {
            "events": {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "events"
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "filtered.events": {
                     "filter": {
                        "terms": {
                            "events.id": [
                               448,
                               435,
                               338,
                               364
                            ]
                         }
                     },
                     "aggs": {
                        "filtered.roles": {
                           "nested": {
                              "path": "events.role"
                           },
                           "aggs": {
                              "filtered": {
                                "filter": {},
                                "aggs": {
                                    "events.name": {
                                       "terms": {
                                          "field": "events.name",
                                          "size": 5
                                       }
                                    },
                                    "events.name_count": {
                                       "cardinality": {
                                          "field": "events.name"
                                       }
                                    }
                                }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

I want to filter events by id, then specific role.name and in the end I need buckets from event.name

Result:

```
"events.name12": {
         "doc_count": 617,
         "events": {
            "doc_count": 1278,
            "filtered.events": {
               "doc_count": 625,
               "filtered.roles": {
                  "doc_count": 625,
                  "filtered": {
                     "doc_count": 625,
                     "events.name": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": []
                     },
                     "events.name_count": {
                        "value": 0
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

I think they are empty because the context is changed to events.role.
But how could I achieve this kind of filtering through different levels of nested field ?

Mapping:

```
{
  "dev.directory.11" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "profile" : {
        "properties" : {
          "company_name" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "email" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          },
          "events" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "categories" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                  "ancestors" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "level" : {
                    "type" : "integer"
                  },
                  "order" : {
                    "type" : "integer"
                  },
                  "value" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  }
                }
              },
              "id" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              },
              "role" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                  "name" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Settings:

```
{
  "dev.directory.11" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1483021523850",
        "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "word_delimiter" : {
              "split_on_numerics" : "false",
              "generate_word_parts" : "true",
              "preserve_original" : "true",
              "generate_number_parts" : "true",
              "catenate_all" : "true",
              "split_on_case_change" : "true",
              "type" : "word_delimiter",
              "catenate_numbers" : "true"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "default" : {
              "filter" : [ "lowercase", "word_delimiter" ],
              "char_filter" : [ "html_strip", "replace" ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "whitespace"
            }
          },
          "char_filter" : {
            "replace" : {
              "type" : "mapping",
              "mappings" : [ "&=> and " ]
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "0",
        "uuid" : "OrXHzHbtSI-vZAB01ckcEg",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "2030299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please share your schema mappings and settings...

Comment: added. I've tried something with reverse_nested but with no luck.

Comment: "I want to filter events by id, then specific role.name and in the end I need buckets from event.name". so i understand you want to filter the final aggregations based on event.roles. You are not looking to sub-bucket events.name based on events.role

Comment: Yes I need nested filter, but aggregations should depend on some higher level